# Removing padding from the first attribute

Tags: css

So I'm including a header and all of the menu items are spread out with padding shown below:

`#mega-menu-wrap-secondary-menu #mega-menu-secondary-menu > li.mega-menu-item > a.mega-menu-link {`

How would I be able to target the first `<a>` of the above css class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems to lack code as I'm not seeing the padding. However, I think this is what you are after. The [:first-child selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp);

`#mega-menu-wrap-secondary-menu #mega-menu-secondary-menu > li.mega-menu-item > a.mega-menu-link:first-child {`

Comment: @SemirSmajlović Please mark this the correct answer.